# to remove unnecessary space between text and figure on same page

Tags: spacing, floats

What is the command that I can used to remove unnecessary space between text and figure on same page?

Below command doesn't do anything

```
\newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-2.5mm}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Start by looking at your image, put a frame around it (i.e., `\fbox{...}`), then you will see if the image is cropped properly. Many programmes does not crop correctly and leaves lots of white space. In that case it may be best to manually trim the image using an external programme.

Comment: `\vspace` only has an effect in certain positions. Experiment by moving it around a bit, to see if you can get it to do something.

Comment: If, by chance, you mean space between figure and caption, those can be changed by the lengths `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`.

Comment: the space between a float and text on the same page is `\intextsep`; in a `10pt` document it is stretchable, with value `12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt`; i would recommend _only_ changing the `12.0pt` part of the value

Comment: Another way to help diagnose the problem is to turn on `\raggedbottom`.  If the extra space moves from around your figure to the bottom of the page, then the extra space is not in your figure *per se* but added as glue by LaTeX.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes for the commands \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip do we need to use special package. Because it doesn't work for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is in response to the user comment wishing to see an example involving `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`.  No special package is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\rule{2in}{1.5in}
\caption{default space around caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\abovecaptionskip=0ex
\belowcaptionskip=0ex
\begin{figure}[ht]
\rule{2in}{1.5in}
\caption{\textbf{Resetting captionskip parameters}}
\lipsum[4]
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]